# What should be at the second screen to fetch intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Beginner in android.My doubt regarding, I have created an intent in first activity.It is not moving to the second screen.After adding an intent explicitly in first activity, what is the procedure to receive the object of intent in second screen?

Ex:
First screen:

```
   public void onClick(View abc) 
   {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Secondactivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
   }
```

Second screen:

What we have to code here?

It's a big mess for me.Help!!

Comment: You have to add the Activity in Android manifest <activity android:enabled="true" android:name=".Secondactivity" ></activity> then you can call it from any activity in your project

Comment: Before StartActivity(i); you can add Information to the intent for ex you can add i.putExtra("score1", temp);to add temp where temp can be of any type string integer etc.and at receiver side you should add Intent i1 = getIntent(); and i1.getextra(temp,"score1"); the value temp will be accessible in that class and if you need help from particular person you should add comment to his Answer

Comment: you should explain your requirement in question properly so any body can help you

Answer (score 1):

**First Activity ::**

```
 intent.putExtra("key", value);
```

**e.g ::**

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Secondactivity.class);
               i.putExtra("score1", temp);
               startActivity(touchAndShow);
               finish();
```

**second Activity ::**

```
    object temp = i1.getIntExtra("key", 1);
```

**e.g :**

```
    Intent i1 = getIntent();
    int temp = i1.getIntExtra("tranningscore2", 1);
```

Comment: Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.

Answer (score 0):

On any activity you can call `Intent i = getIntent();` this will get you the latest intent that was received by the activity.

you can then get extra values from that intent by calling for example:

`String stringExtra = i.getStringExtra(YOUR_EXTRA_STRING_NAME);`.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

**@arvind** just create the second xml ,add another class that extends activity, and set the content view  in second class.
and add that class in your manifest file